# android interface error ImageButton

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

Hi i have an app that is a gallery of images.

The problem is that, i have buttons to move between images on the center of the app and i want them at 75% of the margin of top.

The question is : **Can i put it on % of the screen instead of dp?**

The error is that if i use `margin_bottom` it crashes.

Here is my code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/color_fondo"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/barra"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"a
    android:src="@drawable/cabecera" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/barra"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/pb1"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/img1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imgbtnshare1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@null"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/compartir4" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imgbtn2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/imgbtnshare1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/izquierda42" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imgbtn1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imgbtn2"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/derecha42" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may get the `Layout` size and then calculate your buttons top margin as proportion of that:

**NOTE**: You cannot get the layout size in `onCreate()` since it's not set yet. Do it in `onWindowFocusChanged` method of your `Activity`.

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.YourXML);

@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged (boolean hasFocus) {
        // The layout has been drawn here 
        // so the Height and Width have been computed 
        int width = relativeLayout.getWidth();
        int height = relativeLayout.getHeight(); 
}

int topMargin = height * 0.75;
```

And set it programmatically:

```
LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(
                                  LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,      
                                  LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                            );

layoutParams.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
yourbutton.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```